# Where is my host-only adapter in my Ubuntu network settings?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

Usually I use virtual machine (Virtualbox) in Windows 7. Then there are "host-only adapter" in network and sharing center. But how to configure my host-only adapter in Ubuntu? Even it doesn't exist.

[[image: screenshot]]

Comment: actually, you can call me newbie as ubuntu user..

Answer (score 0):

Host only adapter is not set in network manager . If you want to set host only adapter , open virtualbox - File - Preferences - Network - Host only network - press add button - configure it(Press screw button) - press button ok .

Comment: Your welcome . Its solved ?